# I cannot see site column in Content Query Filters

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server, content-query-web-part

I've made a CQ web part. Before I made a site column call "Assigned to CC" which is multiple user column. I wanted to filter my web part so each person can see the item that "Assigned to cc" contains his\her user ([Me] filter). but there is a problem that Assigned to CC does not show up in columns for filter in web part properties. it seems that I only can filter with OOTB SharePoint columns. How can I add my custom column to be filtered?

Comment: Why Can't you reconfigure your web part ? It will be visible to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom columns in CQWP, it's just that you can't use Multiple User column for filter. You can confirm this by creating a single user column and it will appear in the selection box.

Instead of CQWP - consider using Content Search Web Part, if that's available for you (keeping in mind index delay).